# How to CC and BCC in AWS Pinpoint using NodeJS

Tags: aws-sdk-js, aws-pinpoint

I followed the instructions found here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/developerguide/example_pinpoint_SendMessages_section.html

I am able to send emails, but CC and BCC aren't present.

I believe my issue is in this configuration right here (copied from the link above):

```
const params = {
  ApplicationId: projectId,
  MessageRequest: {
    Addresses: {
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: toAddress,
        CcAddresses: ccAddresses,
        BccAddresses: bccAddresses,
      },

      [toAddress]: {
        ChannelType: "EMAIL",
      },
    },
    MessageConfiguration: {
      EmailMessage: {
        FromAddress: senderAddress,
        SimpleEmail: {
          Subject: {
            Charset: charset,
            Data: subject,
          },
          HtmlPart: {
            Charset: charset,
            Data: body_html,
          },
          TextPart: {
            Charset: charset,
            Data: body_text,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

This is the version that I have:

```
"@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint": "^3.183.0",
```

Any one got ideas on what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what I did to solve this. I couldn't find any example with 'client-pinpoint-EMAIL' so here is my own.

1. use a different npm package... not 'client-pinpoint' but rather 'client-pinpoint-email'
2. then use a different function and shape of input to get emails to cc and bcc.

Min code example below:

```
const { PinpointEmail } = require("@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint-email");
const { SendEmailCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-pinpoint-email");


const pinClient = new PinpointEmail({
  region: aws_region,
  credentials: credentials,
});

const senderAddress = "NameOfYourFirm <hello@yourcompany.com>"
const toAddress = 'email_to_send_address@gmail.com'
const ccEmails = ['email_to_cc@gmail.com']

const params = {
      FeedbackForwardingEmailAddress: senderAddress,
      FromEmailAddress: senderAddress,
      ReplyToAddresses: [senderAddress],
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [toAddress],
        CcAddresses: ccEmails,
      },
      Content: {
        Simple: {
          Subject: {
            Charset: charset,
            Data: subject,
          },
          Body: {
            Html: {
              Charset: charset,
              Data: body_html,
            },
          },
        },
      },
    };

 try {
      const data = await pinClient.send(new SendEmailCommand(params));
      console.log("Email sent! Message ID: ", data["MessageId"]);
      return data; 
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    }
```